# Play Framework: coffee script : can't append an item from my database to an ul

Tags: playframework, coffeescript, html-lists

So this is quite embarrassing but I really wanna learn this thing and i can't move on ...

I have this 'bars' application ... I can add bars to my database ... but i can't display them ...

I have this controller:

```
package controllers;   
import java.util.List;
import models.Bar;
import play.*;
import play.data.Form;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.twirl.api.Content;
import views.html.*;
import play.libs.Json;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Hello world"));
    }

    public static Result addBar(){

        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        bar.save();

        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    public static Result getBars(){
        List<Bar> bars = new Model.Finder(String.class, Bar.class).all();

        return ok(Json.toJson(bars));
    }

}
```

And I don't think the problem is here ...
I have  this model :

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Bar extends Model {

    @Id
    public String Id;

    public String name;


    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I don't think this is the problem ...
And I have this coffee script:

```
$ ->
  $.get "/bars", (data) ->
    $.each data, (index, bar) ->
      $('#bars').append $("<li>").text bar.name
```

It seems to be ok, but i think here is the problem ...
Oh, and here is my html file :

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @message

    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascript/index.js")'></script>

    <ul id="bars">

    </ul>

    <form action="@routes.Application.addBar()" method="POST">

    <input type="input" name="name">
    <input type="submit">

    </form>

}
```

And the routes, but i really don't think the problem is here:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /bars                       controllers.Application.addBar()
GET     /bars                       controllers.Application.getBars()
```

Sooo.... How cand I add my bars to the ul, or what am i doin' wrong here ... ?

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: So what is wrong? When you call `$.get "/bars"` in coffee you don't get a list of bar objects? Check in your `getBars` method what you are getting from the DB or use your browser tools ([chrome](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console--net-28167),  [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)) to make sure what the server is sending to your client

Comment: Nope , i don't get anything! And the database works ok... I tried it on another computer too, and still doesn't work, (the display part)...   i changed the method to display the list to solve the problem... anyway ... this is wierd ... i'd like to know what is not ok with that script ...

Comment: You should divide in order to conquer. First, make sure that your API is returning the appropriate data from the endpoint. You can do that with Developer Tools, curl, or lots of other HTTP tools. Second, create a js fiddle and use mock (static) data to render what you intend. If you fail to find out what's wrong, at least you'll know exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: Hi, I just got the same problem with Play Tutorial. I debugged it in Chrome with devtools and I see an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", that's at line 1 in index.coffee. Looks like something is missing. I can't fix it neither, were you able? thanks

Comment: @Leonardo : I wans't able to fix this, so I made jQuery scripts instead  .

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure if this is the right solution, but I got this working by explicitly including jQuery library. I saw in debug console that "$" definition was missing so I knew somehow jQuery wasn't included.
I downloaded the jquery file from their site, then saved the file to *./public/javascripts/* , edited the file *./app/views/main.scala.html* and added the line

`<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-2.1.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

@Flori, thanks for answering my comment

Comment: Waw! I will keep this in mind for the next time I will try to use coffee scripts. Thank you too, for sharing!